# HTML meta refresh less than 1 second?

Tags: html, refresh, meta, movie

Quick question : is it possible to put a refresh less than 1 second in a

My goal is to test the display of images at 1/24 or 1/30 a second to do "moving pictures"...

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Use `JavaScript(Ajax)` or `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout or something like that, and do all of this in one page, because a page cannot load 24 times per second with different images...

Answer (score 0):

You could make effect using something like:

```
            cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0))
```

See http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/